# Penny Arcade tag rename?

Tags: discussion

We've had two questions about Penny Arcade the Game: Gamers vs. Evil [(1)](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/5364/1749) [(2)](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/5347/1749), and both have caused confusion with Penny Arcade: The Card Game for which we've received no questions. I set about to rename the [penny-arcade-the-game] tag to [penny-arcade-gamers-vs-evil], but that's 2 characters too long for a tag name. So I decided to ask a meta question about a trivial little thing that is causing confusion. [penny-arcade-gamers-v-evil] is *so close* (1 character too long), anyone else have any bright ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insofar as both games are clearly labelled "Penny Arcade: The Game" and "Penny Arcade: The Card Game" on the boxes themselves, I would lean toward using the current [penny-arcade-the-game](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/penny-arcade-the-game) tag, with the tag wiki explaining that The Card Game is a different game and would have a different tag (presumably [penny-arcade-card-game](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/penny-arcade-card-game)).  I think the confusion lies more in the fact that most users don't actually know there's more than one Penny Arcade card game out there (I definitely didn't), rather than deficiencies in the tag itself; the fact that they're both card games, and that they're both generically named, doesn't help.

The tag is just a short and quick identifying category.  Clearing up potential confusion is what the tag wiki (and the body of the question itself) is for.

Note that the expansion to The Game is called "Penny Arcade: The Game - Rumble in R'lyeh".  Any "Gamers vs Evil" tag would thus only really make sense for the base game, but not the game series itself (think [dominion](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dominion) vs [dominion-intrigue](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dominion-intrigue) etc.)

Answer (score 0):

How about [penny-arcade-gamers-evil](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/penny-arcade-gamers-evil) ?